# JavaScript clearInterval doesn't work with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable, clearinterval

I'm trying to count up a variable if the draggable is over an image.
It counts very well. But I wanna to stop it, if its out or dropped. This is not working.

```
    var d = 0;
    function time() {
      if (d < 1000) {
        d++;
        document.getElementById('zun').innerHTML = d;
      } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }


    $( "#hand" ).draggable({    
      revert: true, 
      revertDuration: 800,  

    });
    $("img.dropimg").droppable({
      accept: '#hand',
      over: function(event, ui) {

       var interval = window.setInterval('time()', 1000);

     },

     out: function(event, ui) {
       window.clearInterval(interval);

     },   
     drop: function() { 
       window.clearInterval(interval);
     }
   });
```

Comment: your var interval is only visible inside the `over:` function, so clearInterval outside that function isn't clearing anything - the keyword is **scope**

Comment: wow, thought I already tried something like this.
But it worked. So easy and but I was..
thank you so much!